# connectivity with SUP server

Tags: sybase

We are trying to connect to SUP database from an application on our iphone....but it is taking a long time to connect to database..
How can we reduce the time to connect to  SUP database from real device(iphone)?
Is there any method to improve the performance of SUP?

Answer (score 0):

One way of influencing response time is to keep frequently accessed MBOs in memory. This is an undocumented, albeit useful if not necessary setting. Set the flag with following URL:

[http://localhost:4040/onepage/servlet/UWPServlet?app=uep&cmd=MobileObjectAdmin.enableInMemoryCache&package_name=&mobile_object_name=&authenticate.user=supAdmin&authenticate.password=s3pAdmin](http://localhost:4040/onepage/servlet/UWPServlet?app=uep&cmd=MobileObjectAdmin.enableInMemoryCache&package_name=%3CpackageID%3E&mobile_object_name=%3CMBO%20Name%3E&authenticate.user=supAdmin&authenticate.password=s3pAdmin)

For viewing the status replace `enableInMemoryCache` with `queryInMemoryCache` in above URL.

Do you mind sharing what average connection time you have been observing?